# Константная ссылка на результат тернарного оператора

Tags: c++, ссылки, ссылка

Почему программа выводит `1`, а не `2`?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x = 1;
    const auto& y = true ? x : 1;
    x = 2;
    std::cout << y << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Хватит использовать `auto`!

Comment: @icYFTL почему?

Comment: https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: @icYFTL так он и продвигает идею AAA :)

Comment: А ой. не та ссылка, но были приколы с ауто

Comment: А почему должно было вывести 2? Тот выражение тоже самое, что: `true ? 1 : 1`

Comment: @gil9red потому что ссылка на `x`, после чего `x` изменяется на `2`

Comment: А Вы сделайте не `true ? x : 1;` а `true ? x : z;`, где `z = 1;`

Comment: @killer, `int x = 1;` тут нет ссылки, только значение. У вас ссылка на `y`

Comment: @EOF сделал `#define z 1` и подставил `z` - всё равно `1` выводит

Comment: А Вы сделайте `int z = 1;`

Comment: @gil9red я имел в виду, что `y` - ссылка на `x`, а не `int x = 1` - ссылка

Comment: @EOF теперь `2` выводит

Comment: Кстати, теги [tag:ссылки] и [tag:ссылка] относятся к ссылкам `C++` или к гиперссылкам сети?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y` - это не ссылка на `x`. Это ссылка на неименованный временный объект, порождаемый выражением `true ? x : 1`, который инициализируется либо изначальным значением `x`, либо литералом 1, и время жизни которого продлевается до конца области видимости ссылки.

Comment: То есть это то же самое, что написать `const auto y = ...` без `&`? Если да, то почему нет разницы?

Comment: Нет, это не то же самое. `const auto y = true ? x : 1;` создает обычную переменную без всяких ссылок.

Comment: В чём отличие ссылки на неименованный временный объект от обычной переменной в данном случае?

Comment: @killer в том что в одном случае получается две сущности - временный объект и ссылка на него, причем эта ссылка продлевает жизнь временного объекта до конца области видимости ссылки, а в другом - только одна - сам объект. хотя на результате `std::cout << y` это не отражается.

Answer (score 0):

В случаи:

```
int x = 1;
int z = 1;
const auto& k = true ? x : z;
```

ссылке присваивается то ли объект `x`, то ли объект `z`, т.е. вы получаете ожидаемое вами поведение программы.

В вашем примере ссылке присваивается то ли **временный объект** int(1), то ли такой же(в тернарной операции обe операнда должны быть такими же) временный объект `int(x)`. Вот и получаете ссылку на другой объект.